# how to free device_vector<int>

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I allocated some space using thrust device vector as follows:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> s(10000000000);
```

How do i free this space explicitly *and correctly*?

Comment: Are you sure you allocated a device vector with 10 billion elements? That requires 40Gb of free memory, which I am very confident no NVIDIA GPU has.

Comment: @talonmies you want to flag question for fiction?

Answer (score 11):

`device_vector` deallocates the storage associated when it goes out of scope, just like any standard c++ container.

If you'd like to deallocate any Thrust `vector`'s storage manually during its lifetime, you can do so using the following recipe:

```
// empty the vector
vec.clear();

// deallocate any capacity which may currently be associated with vec
vec.shrink_to_fit();
```

The `swap` trick mentioned in Roger Dahl's answer should also work.

Comment: How does the device_vector know that it has gone out of scope. Suppose after a particular line of code, i never access the device vector. Will thrust deallocate it for 'right' after that line has executed during program execution

Comment: @Programmer Let me give you an example. If you declare vector as a local variable in a function, when you exit the function, the destructor of that variable will get called, hence freeing the memory.

Answer (score 9):

`clear()` sets the size of the vector to 0, but may not release the associated memory. The standard way to release the memory with STL is to swap the vector with an empty vector. It should work for Thrust as well.

```
v.clear();
device_vector<T>().swap(v);
```